# Word File Names Auto Created

Tags: microsoft-word

Folks

File names like this are being created 2da380dc31a033e59b33fc9e006c0cad5 and I cannot see why?
If I click on them the data from the file still exists!!
Its created 30+ of them with some being created 3,5, even 9 times so files end with (9)

It's for a friend by the way not on my PC so I am struggling in getting info from him as he's not very PC literate.

Comment: There are configuration files from updates I suppose...

Comment: Good thought, however, if the documents are opened (double-click) the original document is there. So can that still be an update???

Comment: That's because the recuperation tool. Windows needs to store the update files to restore the old configuration. Maybe you can delete that files using the free space tool of windows selecting "delete update files"